# Where is python's logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler?

Tags: python, logging, pypi

I'm building a project with python 2.7, and would love to have my logs rotate (managed in the usual way by `logrotate`). Python logging has a mechanism for handling this- `WatchedFileHandler`, however, I dont know how to install or where to find it!

```
.virtualenv/bin/python -c 'import logging; print logging.__version__'
> 0.5.1.2
```

this seems like the most current version, however, the `handlers` package is no where to be found. Am I going crazy?

Comment: Additional info that I might have left out: this is using the default python 2 on a raspberry pi zero.

Answer (score -1):

You should not use the `logging` package from PyPI but just the built-in [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html) module:

```
>>> import logging.handlers
>>> logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler
<class 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler'>
```

Comment: I havent installed logging through pypi- i was assuming that i needed to.

Comment: Just to clarify; I've only used the default logging module. the problem persists, however.